# WooCommerce different order minimum for free shipping per country

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my WooCommerce shop, it's possible for people to order from two countries.

Ok, now I want to set free shipping for people who order a total above 100,- in one country (this is easy to do in the delivery settings) but when I want to set this minimum for another country, I have no idea where or how I can do this?

If someone can point me the road or has any suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by default in WC, you need a plugin for that.

One I recommend (duh) is [WooCommerce Advanced Free Shipping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-advanced-free-shipping/).

PS. This question will most likely be considered unrelevant for StackOverflow.
Cheers

Comment: How to get minimum amount for free shipping in the same plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Do not think so.You just handle the country separately as shipping zones. If you have country A. You make shipping zone for that and you put for the free shipping 100 and for country B another shipping zoneand add free shipping for that.